# Implement RTL functionality in a Material UI app

Tags: javascript, i18n

I've been tasked with adding *RTL support* to Material UI project. I've stripped non-essential code down to a simplified version of the `UI/Theme` module. My solution involves the following:

- a `language` module which has a list of RTL language identifiers and some methods for determining language *directionality*;
- a theme-specific `i18n` module that defines the `initial` styles and the relevant style property *accessors*;
- refactoring the `DefaultTheme` for using the *i18n-related* styles and ensuring updates whenever language *directionality* has changed.

The entry point is `getTheme`, which now receives an object containing both the `themeName` and the current `language`.

I'm looking for an evaluation of clean code and the overall quality of this implementaion. Thanks in advance.

---

Original `UI/Theme/index.js`:

```js
import DefaultTheme from './DefaultTheme';

export const themes = {
  'default': DefaultTheme,
};

export const getTheme = (themeName) =>
  themes[themeName] || themes['default'];
```

New `UI/Theme/index.js`:

```js
import DefaultTheme from './DefaultTheme';

export const themes = {
  [DefaultTheme.name]: DefaultTheme,
};

export function getTheme({ themeName, language }) {
  if (themes[themeName] == null) {
    console.warn(`No theme named '${themeName}'; using '${DefaultTheme.name}'`);
    return DefaultTheme;
  }
  
  return themes[themeName];
};
```

---

Original `UI/Theme/DefaultTheme.js`:

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// Theme for Material-UI components
const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      h6: {
        fontWeight: 400,
      },
    },
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        '&:before': {
          borderBottom: `1px solid #BBBBBB`,
        },
      },
    },
    MuiIconButton: {
      root: {
        color: '#111',
      },
    },
    MuiTab: {
      textColorPrimary: {
        color: '#fff',
      },
      root: {
        paddingTop: 0,
        paddingBottom: 0,
        minHeight: 32,
      },
    },
    MuiButtonBase: {
      root: {
        cursor: 'default',
      },
    },
    MuiTableCell: {
      sizeSmall: {
        paddingTop: 0,
        paddingBottom: 0,
      },
    },
    MuiCheckbox: {
      root: {
        marginTop: -9,
        marginBottom: -9,
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        fontWeight: 400,
      },
    },
  },
});

const theme = {
  muiTheme,
};
export default theme;
```

New `UI/Theme/DefaultTheme.js`:

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { derive, compose, blend } from '../../Utils/Object';
import { text, initial as i18n } from './i18n';

// Theme for Material-UI components
const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    ...i18n,
    MuiTypography: blend({
      h6: {
        fontWeight: 400,
      },
    }, [text.root]),
    MuiInput: blend({
      underline: {
        '&:before': {
          borderBottom: `1px solid #BBBBBB`,
        },
      },
    }, [text.root]),
    MuiIconButton: {
      root: {
        color: '#111',
      },
    },
    MuiTab: blend({
      textColorPrimary: {
        color: '#fff',
      },
      root: {
        paddingTop: 0,
        paddingBottom: 0,
        minHeight: 32,
      },
    }, [text.root]),
    MuiButtonBase: {
      root: {
        cursor: 'default',
      },
    },
    MuiTableCell: {
      sizeSmall: {
        paddingTop: 0,
        paddingBottom: 0,
      },
    },
    MuiCheckbox: {
      root: {
        marginTop: -9,
        marginBottom: -9,
      },
    },
    MuiButton: blend({
      root: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        fontWeight: 400,
      },
    }, [text.label]),
  },
});

const theme = {
  /**
   * Obtains the `muiTheme` instance.
   *
   * This property accessor ensures that the `muiTheme` instance 
   * will be reapplied by `ThemeProvider` on every update, _only_
   * when language directionality has changed.
   */
  get muiTheme() {
    const former = language.is_ltr;
    const current = language.is_ltr;
    return former !== current ? derive(muiTheme) : muiTheme;
  },
};
export default compose({ name: 'default', }, theme);
```

---

New `UI/Theme/i18n.js`:

```js
function _direction(key) {
  return {
    [key]: {
      get direction() {
        const { is_ltr } = language;
        return is_ltr ? 'unset' : 'rtl';
      },
    },
  };
}
export const text = {
  root: _direction('root'),
  label: _direction('label'),
};

function _order(key) {
  return {
    [key]: {
      get order() {
        const { is_ltr } = language;
        return is_ltr ? 'unset' : (styles.order?.rtl ?? 100);
      },
    },
  };
}
export const icon = {
  root: _order('root'),
};

const styles = {
  order: {
    rtl: 100,
  },
};

export default styles;

export const initial = {
  MuiTypography: text.root,
  MuiInput: text.root,
  MuiTab: text.root,
  MuiFormControlLabel: text.root,
  MuiTextField: text.root,
  
  MuiButton: text.label,
  
  MuiSvgIcon: icon.root,
};
```

New `Utils/i18n/language.js`:

```js
import { isObject, isString } from '../Object';

const _rtl = new Set([
  /******* Hebrew scripts *******/
  'he'/* Hebrew */,
  'ji'/* Yiddish */,
  'yi'/* Yiddish */,
  
  /******* Arabic scripts *******/
  'ar'/* Arabic */,
  'az'/* Azerbaijani */,
  'jv'/* Javanese */,
  'ks'/* Kashmiri */,
  'kk'/* Kazakh */,
  'ku'/* Kurdish */,
  'ms'/* Malay */,
  'ml'/* Malayalam */,
  'ps'/* Pashto */,
  'fa'/* Persian */,
  'pa'/* Punjabi */,
  'sd'/* Sindhi */,
  'so'/* Somali */,
  'tk'/* Turkmen */,
  'ug'/* Uighur */,
  'ur'/* Urdu */,
]);

export default class Language {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = '--';
    if (isString(name)) {
      this._name = /^([\w]{2})?/.exec(name)[1] ?? this._name;
    }
  }
  
  get direction() {
    return this.is_ltr ? 'ltr' : 'rtl';
  }
  
  get is_ltr() {
    return !_rtl.has(this._name);
  }
  
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  
  static from(lang) {
    return isObject(lang) ? lang : new Language(lang);
  }
  
  static directionFor(lang) {
    return Language.from(lang)?.direction;
  }
  
  static is_ltr(lang) {
    return Language.from(lang)?.is_ltr;
  }
}
```

New `Utils/Object.js`:

```js
/**
 * Useful for storing some metadata for e.g. `explode()` and `assemble()`.
 */
const _records = new WeakMap();

/**
 * When given a `record` argument, stores it in `_records` with `subject`
 * as the key; otherwise, returns the value in `_records` stored at  
 * `subject`.
 */
function _refer(subject, record) {
  if (subject instanceof Void) return;
  if (arguments.length < 2) return _records.get(subject);
  _records.set(subject, record);
  return record;
}

/**
 * Useful for checking is some value is `null` or `undefined`.
 */
export const Void = {
  [Symbol.hasInstance](subject) {
    return typeof subject === 'undefined' || subject === null;
  },
}

/**
 * Useful for checking if some value is falsy and not `undefined`.
 */
export const False = {
  [Symbol.hasInstance](subject) {
    return subject !== undefined && !subject;
  },
}

/**
 * Useful for checking if some value is truthy.
 */
export const True = {
  [Symbol.hasInstance](subject) {
    return !!subject;
  },
}

/**
 * Useful for checking if some value supports iteration.
 */
export const Iterable = {
  [Symbol.hasInstance](subject) {
    if (subject instanceof Void) return false;
    return isFunction(subject[Symbol.iterator]);
  },
}

/**
 * Useful for checking if some value is a generator.
 */
export const Generator = {
  [Symbol.hasInstance](subject) {
    if (subject instanceof Void) return false;
    return subject[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'Generator';
  },
}

export function isObject(subject) {
  return typeof subject === 'object';
}

export function isString(subject) {
  return typeof subject === 'string';
}

/**
 * Checks if given `subject` is an _actual_ number, i.e. not NaN.
 */
export function isNumber(subject) {
  return typeof subject === 'number' && !isNaN(subject);
}

export const { isArray } = Array;

export function isFunction(subject) {
  return typeof subject === 'function';
}

export const { isExtensible } = Object;

/**
 * Check if given `subject` has a property named '`key`'.
 */
export function scan(subject, key) {
  return subject != null ? Reflect.has(subject, key) : false;
}

/**
 * Useful for getting some value (by given `key`) from given `subject`
 * in a null-safe manner.
 *
 * Example:
 *   tap(foo, bar)
 * where `foo` may be nullish and/or the key stored in `bar` may or may
 * not exist in `foo`.  
 */
export function tap(subject, key) {
  return subject != null ? Reflect.get(subject, key) : undefined;
}

/**
 * Obtains the enumerable own property keys of given `subject`,
 * in a null-safe manner.
 */
export function keysOf(subject) {
  return subject != null ? Object.keys(subject) : undefined;
}

/**
 * Does the same as `keysOf()`, however it falls back to an empty array
 * instead of `undefined`.
 */
keysOf.loose = function(subject) {
  return keysOf(subject) ?? [];
}

/**
 * Obtains the enumerable own property entries on given `subject`;
 * properly handles Array and Function inputs.
 *
 * Example:
 *   explode(null)
 * returns `undefined`.
 *
 * Example:
 *   explode({ get foo() { return 'bar'; } })
 * returns `[['foo', 'bar']]`.
 *
 * Example:
 *   explode(Object.assign(['foo', 'bar'], { baz: 'qux' }))
 * returns `[['baz', 'qux']]` and stores `['foo', 'bar']` (i.e. the
 * original array object) in `_records`, for later.
 */
export function explode(subject) {
  if (subject instanceof Void) return;
  const out = Object.entries(subject);
  switch (true) {
    case isArray(subject):
      const record = _refer(out, []);
      return out.filter(([k, v]) => {
        if (/\s/.test(k)) return true;
        const i = parseInt(k);
        if (!isNumber(i)) return true;
        record[i] = v;
        return false;
      });
    case isFunction(subject):
    case subject instanceof Generator:
      _refer(out, subject);
      return out;
  }
}

function _assemble(target, source) {
  if (target instanceof Void) return target;
  if (!(source instanceof Iterable)) return target;
  
  for (const [key, value] of source) {
    target[key] = value;
  }
  
  return target;
}

/**
 * Constructs a new object from the entries found by iterating 
 * given `subject`. Uses any values found in `_records` (stored
 * by previous calls to `explode()` for e.g.). If any `sources`
 * are given, they are '_assemble'd to given `subject` (if 
 * non-nullish).
 */
export function assemble(subject, ...sources) {
  if (arguments.length === 0) return {};
  if (sources.length === 0) {
    if (subject instanceof Void) return;
  
    const schema = isArray(subject) ? subject : subject.entries();
    const record = _refer(schema);
    if (isArray(record)) {
      return _assemble([...record], schema);
    }
    
    // TODO: Handle `Function` and `Generator` here
  
    return Object.fromEntries(schema);
  }
  
  if (subject instanceof Void) return subject;
  
  for (const source of sources) {
    _assemble(subject, source);
  }
  
  return subject;
}

/**
 * Assigns all enumerable own values from each element of
 * `sources` onto given `target`, in a null-safe manner.
 */
export function extend(target, ...sources) {
  if (target instanceof Void) return target;
  return Object.assign(target, ...sources);
}

/**
 * Returns the value at given second argument (as key) if a string,
 * otherwise constructs a new object with all of given `subject`'s
 * properties filtered by the contents of the second argument (as
 * `keys`).
 */
export function extract(subject, keys) {
  if (subject instanceof Void) return subject;
  if (isString(keys)) return subject[keys];
  if (!(keys instanceof Iterable)) return { ...subject };
  
  const out = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    const value = subject[key];
    if (value === undefined) continue;
    out[key] = value;
  }
  
  return out;
}

/**
 * Obtains the descriptor of given `subject`'s own property at
 * given `key`.
 */
function _describe(subject, key) {
  if (subject instanceof Void) return;
  return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(subject, key);
}

/**
 * Obtains the descriptor of given `subject`'s own property at
 * given `key`, or all property descriptors if no `key` is given; 
 * only the enumerable own properties are inspected.
 */
export function describe(subject, key) {
  if (subject instanceof Void) return;
  if (arguments.length > 1) return _describe(subject, key);
  return assemble(keysOf(subject).map(k => [k, _describe(subject, k)]));
}

/**
 * Attaches (`define`s) given property (`key` + `spec`) or properties
 * (given as `key`) onto `target`, in a null-safe manner.
 */
export function define(target, key, spec) {
  if (target instanceof Void) return target;

  if (arguments.length > 2) {
    key = {
      [key]: {
        ...spec,
        configurable: spec?.configurable ?? true,
        enumerable: spec?.enumerable ?? true,
        ...(
          scan(spec, 'value') ?
            { writable: spec?.writable ?? false } :
            null
        ),
      },
    };
  }

  if (key instanceof Void) return target;

  return Object.defineProperties(target, key);
}

/**
 * Attaches (`define`s) given `key`-`value` pair as a new property
 * upon given `target`, in a null-safe manner.
 */
export function install(target, key, value) {
  return define(target, key, { value, writable: true, });
}

/**
 * Obtains an unified descriptors object based on given `sources`.
 */
function toSchema(sources) {
  return extend({}, ...sources.map(src => describe(src)));
}

/**
 * Defines all enumerable own properties of each given `schema`
 * onto given `target`. Returns a loose replica of given `target`
 * if no `schema` is given.
 *
 * Example:
 *   merge({ foo: 'foo' }, { get bar() { return 'bar'; } })
 * returns:
 *   { foo: 'foo', get bar() { return 'bar'; } }
 */
export function merge(target, ...schemas) {
  if (!isExtensible(target)) return target;
  if (schemas.length === 0) return merge({}, target);
  return define(target, toSchema(schemas));
}

/**
 * Constructs a new object inheriting given `subject` and
 * enhanced by given `schema`, in a null-safe manner.
 */
export function derive(subject, schema) {
  return Object.create(subject ?? null, schema ?? undefined);
}

/**
 * Returns a new getter descriptor which returns the value at
 * given `key` from given `subject`.
 */
function _getter(subject, key) {
  return {
    get() { return subject[key]; },
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
  };
}

/**
 * Constructs a new object which effectively `mirrors` given `subject`
 * via delegation by defining property getters to corresponding
 * own enumerable properties of `subject`. If `inherit` is truthy,
 * the given `subject` is also inherited.
 */
export function mirror(subject, inherit) {
  if (subject instanceof Void) return subject;
  const schema = assemble(keysOf(subject).map((k) => [k, _getter(subject, k)]));
  return inherit ? derive(subject, schema) : define({}, schema);
}

/**
 * Constructs a new object that inherits from givenb `template`
 * and also has all enumerable own properties of every given
 * `schema` defined.
 */
export function compose(template, ...schemas) {
  return derive(template, toSchema(schemas));
}

/**
 * This is basically a deep version of `merge()` that recursively
 * `merge`s given `extra` on given `target`.
 */
function _blend(target, extra) {
  if (!isExtensible(target)) return merge(extra);
  
  for (const key of keysOf.loose(extra)) {
    const spec = describe(extra, key);
    if (scan(target, key)) {
      install(target, key, _blend(target[key], extra[key]));
    } else {
      define(target, key, spec);
    }
  }
  return target;
}

/**
 * This is basically a deep version of `merge()` that recursively
 * `merge`s every element of given `extra`s array on given `target`.
 *
 * Example:
 *   blend({ foo: { bar: 'baz' } }, { foo: { get baz() { return 'qux'; } } })
 * returns `{ foo: { bar: 'baz', get baz() { return 'qux'; } } }`.
 *
 * Example:
 *   blend({ foo: { bar: 'baz', qux: 'quux' } }, { foo: { bar: 'qux' } })
 * returns `{ foo: { bar: 'qux', qux: 'quux' } }`.
 */
export function blend(target, extras) {
  if (target instanceof Void) return target;
  if (!(extras instanceof Iterable)) return target;
  for (const extra of extras) {
    target = _blend(target, extra);
  }
  return target;
}
```

Comment: Please don't modify the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against site policy. More reviews may be coming in, and it gets awfully confusing if answers review different versions of the same code.

Comment: (To whoever challenged *authorship of code*: please disclose cause.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Default or named exports?** In some of the modules, you use default exports, and in others, you use named exports. It's not much of a problem, but the inconsistency has a chance of causing problems later, especially once you have lots of modules in a project.

> I want to import Foo. Now, do I do `import Foo from './Foo';` or do I do `import { Foo } from './Foo';`?

I'd prefer to choose one style and stick with it in most cases.

**Comparison** You have `if (themes[themeName] == null) {`. This is a bit strange for a few reasons: if a property isn't defined on the object, it'll be `undefined`, not `null`. You can use `==` to coerce `undefined` on the left to `null`, but that's weird. Readers of the code will have to understand the [weird ways that `==` works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494), which should not be a requirement. When you need to compare, better to [always use `===`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq). Here, since a theme on the `themes` object will be truthy, I'd consider:

```
if (themes[themeName]) {
  return themes[themeName];
}
```

**`_rtl`**: Modules have their own self-contained scope, so I don't think the `_` adds anything useful, and the variable name could be made more precise by calling it something like `rtlLanguages`.

**Language constructor and regex** A few things stood out to me here. You have:

```
constructor(name) {
  this._name = '--';
  if (isString(name)) {
    this._name = /^([\w]{2})?/.exec(name)[1] ?? this._name;
  }
}
```

You import `isString` from a big file elsewhere in order to test if `name` is a string. When I saw that, I thought "*Why is that an import and a function call, rather than just a `typeof` check in the constructor? It sounds like `isString` is doing a more elaborate check that requires generalization*" - but it's actually only doing a `typeof` check. Putting the logic of such a trivial check so far from where the check is needed doesn't seem right - I'd inline `typeof name === 'string'` instead, it'll make more sense at a glance.

The regular expression can be improved.

- If a single character needs to be quantified, there's no need to put it into a character set - just put the quantifier to the right of the token, `\w{2}`.
- Optional capture groups aren't very intuitive. I bet if you took a survey of whether a non-matching group returned `undefined`, `null`, or the empty string, the results wouldn't be much greater than chance. I'd prefer to have a regular expression that matches 2 characters spanning the whole string instead: `/^\w{2}$/.exec(name)?.[0] || this._name`
- Rather than assigning to `this._name` twice, you can alternate with `'--'` on the right if you want. (Just a suggestion, I find it more elegant, but you might not like it)

  ```
  const possibleName = typeof name === 'string' && /^\w{2}$/.exec(name)?.[0];
  this._name = possibleName || '--';
  ```

**Language module** The whole language module seems oddly complex. If it were me, I'd find it simpler and more intuitive to just export a function that checks if the passed element is in the Set: `export const isLTR = lang => !rtlLanguages.has(lang);` and nothing else. You also currently aren't differentiating between languages which are LTR, and languages which are unknown. It may well not matter, depending on how it's used, but that's just something to keep in mind.

**Types** There are quite a lot of places in the code where you're checking the types of arguments before proceeding to operate on them, like `if (subject instanceof Void) return false;`. You might consider using Typescript to *enforce* correct typings so that nonsensical function calls generate warnings in the caller. Typescript can turn many potential runtime errors and bugs into easy-to-fix compile-time warnings. It takes some time to get used to, but for anything other than a tiny script, I find it immensely helpful. Just an idea. [JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59253145) arguments is another more lightweight option.